# Flying-Saucer generates half-empty pdf page on page 1

Tags: pdf, flying-saucer

I am just fiddeling around with Flying Saucer to generate a PDF from a plain HTML Template I wrote.

Unfortunately, flying saucer seems to generate 1/2 empty page on my first page so the main content actually just begins on the second half of the first page.

There is really not much to show as I am working with a normal html page that lies in a String Object consisting of some table and well-formed html. Displaying the html shows exactly what I want and the part that gets rendered does also look great and as expected - but there is half an empty page...

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer;
    PdfImportedPage page;

    byte[] pdfDaten;
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    PdfReader pdfPage = pdfBuilder.doRenderGeneratorToPDF(html_page);
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfPage, 1);
    document.newPage();
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    document.close();

    baos.flush();
    pdfDaten = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return pdfDaten;
```

Did anybody else experience this problem and has a hint or solution?

Comment: Do you really use Flying Saucer? In the sample code, there is no call to Flying Saucer, only direct calls to IText. Also, the definition of `pdfBuilder` is not given.

Comment: @obourgain thanks for coming back. Yes it is hidden but not much is happening - but lucky me - I found the solution and it was a problem I did myself. I had forgotten to remove the landscape mode as page orientation!